# If grep file wordcount equals number then

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have this script - it's not working. I want the script to return a list of all files in which the keyword 'keyword' occurs two times.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in * ; do
    if [ $(grep 'keyword' $file | wc -l) -eq 2 ]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: It tried it and it seems to work fine. Please tell us in which way it's not working and show a minimal example if possible. Also, use `"$file"` instead of `$file` to guard your script against filenames with spaces.

Comment: I suppose this would also miss instances in which `keyword` appeared twice in the same line.

Comment: @Eduardo I would give you the answer, but it's a comment. Anyway you were right.. I just didn't wait long enough for the output to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
grep -c 'keyword' * | sed -n -e '/:2$/s/:2$//p'
```

Comment: +1. I'd replace the final grep|sed with `awk -F: '$2 == 2 {print $1}'`

Comment: @glennjackman: I thought of this, but the file name may contain `:`

Comment: @glennjackman: But of course I was still being silly, since there's no need to `grep` again after I'm calling `sed` anyway. Answer edited.

Comment: Follow up question: Would /:1$/s/:1$//p count only one time occurences of keyword or also files that have two time occurences?

Comment: Regarding my follow-up question I found the answer by testing now. And the "1$" matches correctly files that have keyword only one time written in it. However if keyword occurs two times in one line, as DSM mentioned above, 1$ matches also files where keyword occurs more than once.

Comment: @StephanKristyn: Correct, multiple times on one line would cause this approach to break. Working around that would require a tool that reports matches once per file but more than once per line. Trivial example: `perl -e 'my $p=shift;undef$/;foreach my$f(@ARGV){open($fh,"<",$f) or die $!;my$d=<$fh>;print $f,":",scalar(@{[$d=~/$p/g]}),"\n"};close($fh)or die$!;' 'keyword' * | sed -n -e '/:2$/s/:2$//p'`

Comment: Invoking sed or awk instead of a simple wc is a waste of resources.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the '-o' option of grep, which will output every matches in its own line instead of printing the full line. It will also work when you have 2+ occurences on the same line.

```
grep -o 'keyword' $file | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`ls -1 | grep .*keyword.*keyword.*`

Comment: This will yield results for files that have keyword in a single line twice at least once. :)